# JBPM to Drools Flow - Is there a documented migration path?

Tags: java, jbpm, drools-flow

I'm currently using a fairly old version of JBPM for workflow processing as part of a larger project. I'm investigating the possibility of moving to the Drools Flow library as a replacement to JBPM.

I've found a lot of documentation about migrating from OSWorkflow to Drools, but can't find anything for migrating from JBPM to Drools Flow. Are there any similar, automatic tools for migration from JBPM? And if not, is there any documentation describing the steps involved in a manual migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be one for JBPM5 which is a almost direct port of Drools Flow. JBPM5 actually uses drools maven artifacts internally and as far as I know, JBoss has been trying to merge those two projects for some time. Of course you can still use drools integration, drools expert with JBPM5, and you use Eclipse Drools editors to modify it's BPMN 2.0 processes. But I digress.

The migration tool is not out yet but I bet you could ask the author directly about that:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/jBPM5migrationtoolproject